# Append a repeated element name in XML using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

If I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<properties>
    <property>
        <picture>http://example.com/image1.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://example.com/image2.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://example.com/image3.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://example.com/image4.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://example.com/image5.jpg</picture>
    </property>
</properties>
```

How would I go about transforming it to where each picture URL element is unique like this:

```
<properties>
    <property>
        <picture1>http://example.com/image1.jpg</picture1>
        <picture2>http://example.com/image2.jpg</picture2>
        <picture3>http://example.com/image3.jpg</picture3>
        <picture4>http://example.com/image4.jpg</picture4>
        <picture5>http://example.com/image5.jpg</picture5>
    </property>
</properties>
```

Am I correct in assuming that there must be the same amount of  elements per  even if some of the  elements contain empty values (the number of picture URLs does vary by property)?

Comment: You seem to be missing a word: "there must be the same amount of elements per ____ even if..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This short and simple transformation** (no axes used):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="picture">
   <xsl:element name="picture{position()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<properties>
    <property>
        <picture>http://example.com/image1.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://example.com/image2.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://example.com/image3.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://example.com/image4.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://example.com/image5.jpg</picture>
    </property>
</properties>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<properties>
   <property>
      <picture1>http://example.com/image1.jpg</picture1>
      <picture2>http://example.com/image2.jpg</picture2>
      <picture3>http://example.com/image3.jpg</picture3>
      <picture4>http://example.com/image4.jpg</picture4>
      <picture5>http://example.com/image5.jpg</picture5>
   </property>
</properties>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Overriding the **[identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** for `picture` elements.
2. Using **[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)** and the **[`position()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-position)** function within the `name` attribute of **[`xsl:element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl%3aelement)**.
3. Use of **[`xsl:strip-space`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-strip-space)**.

Answer (score 3):

Use `count(preceding-sibling::*)+1` to get the index of the current element.

Complete example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- override for picture elements to rename element -->
<xsl:template match="picture">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}{count(preceding-sibling::*)+1}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Kurt, you could also use `position()` instead of `count(preceding-sibling::*)+1`. Right Francis?

Comment: No, you cannot. It will count white space nodes as well, not only elements.

Comment: @FrancisAvila: Actually one *can* use `position()` in the AVT -- see my answer.